# Морские судА или морские сУдна — как правильно?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь, множественное-число

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать:
*морские (воздушные) **судА** или **сУдна**?*

Answer (score 3):

*Сложность склонения имени существительного **"судно"** во множественном числе исходит из того, что это слово многозначно. Судном может называться как **транспорт** (водный или воздушный), так и **посуда**, используемая во время ухода за больными.*

***Правильно просклонять слово*** [транспортное] **"судно", во множественном числе нужно так:**
И.п. (навстречу шли что?) - **суда**; *по реке плывут суда.*
Р.п. (чего было мало?) - **судов**; *я не вижу судов на море*.
Д.п. (дали названия чему?) - **судам**; *этим судам даны новые названия.*
В.п. (трудно разглядеть что?) - **суда**; *люблю красивые суда.*
Т.п. (чем плыть?) - **судами**; *кто управляет этими судами?*
П.п. (мечтал о чём?) - о **судах**; *книга о судах мне очень понравилась.*

[ **Для справки.** ***Судно*** в значении "инвентарь для ухода":
И.п. В каких магазинах продаются **судна**?
Р.п. В больнице не хватает **суден**.
Д.п. Этим **суднам** уже сто лет, пора их выбросить.
В.п. Выносить **судна** - обязанность младших медицинских работников.
Т.п. Кто заведует **суднами** в этой палате?
П.п. На планёрке в больнице говорили **о суднах**.]

Правильно будет: ***морские (воздушные) судА.***
[**Судно**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Обсуждение и "разбор" этого вопроса можно посмотреть [**здесь.**](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/747740-kak-prosklonjat-po-padezham-slovo-sudno-mnozhestvennoe-chislo.html)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно только **суда**.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE&all=x

Судна - это или больничные сосуды, или украинизм.